# Minizinc - Constraint that checks element match

Tags: minizinc

If I have a 2D decision variable array and a 1D array of  set, how do I add constraint to check that values in decision variables should match from 1D array?

For example,

```
array[1..3, 1..2] of var 1..10: x;
array[1..3] of set of 1..10: y;

And y is = [{2, 6, 7, 8},
 {1, 2, 3},
 {1, 2, 7, 8, 1, 5, 1},
];
```

I want to add constraint that ensures that x keeps only values contained in y.
For example, the rule is that values of x0, x1 should be one among first set of values of y {2, 6, 7, 8}. Values of x2, x3 should be amonst the second set of values of y {1, 2, 3} and so on.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `y` is defined as parameter (i.e. not defined with `var`) as in your example, then you can extract the values of `y` as a set (`vals`) like this:

```
array[1..3] of set of 1..10: y = [{2, 6, 7, 8},
 {1, 2, 3},
 {1, 2, 7, 8, 1, 5, 1},
];

% convert the values 
set of int: vals = { val | row in y, val in row  };
        
array[1..3, 1..2] of var vals : x;

output [
  "vals:\(vals)\nx:\(x)\n"
];
```

Update: Here's a suggestion for the updated version of the question. Here we constrain the `x` variables in the `i'th` to values be only the `i'th` row in `y`, i.e. the `i'th` set in `y`.  As before I assume that the values in `y` are plain integers (not decision variables):

```
array[1..3] of set of 1..10: y = [{2, 6, 7, 8},
 {1, 2, 3},
 {1, 2, 7, 8, 1, 5, 1},
];

array[1..3, 1..2] of var int : x;

% Ensure that the i'th row in x only contains values 
% that are in the i'th row/set of y
constraint
  forall(i in 1..3) (
     forall(j in 1..2) (
        x[i,j] in y[i]
     )
  )
;

output [
"x:\(x)\n",
];
```

Comment: I'm not sure how `exists` would help here. Do you have something special in mind?

Comment: Hello Sir, I was thinking something like global constraint 'among'. Can this be applied here?

Comment: If `y` contains plain integers and you just want to use the values in `y` as the domain of `x` then `among` is an overkill. There are certainly use cases for `among`, but this don't seems to be one of them.

Comment: Sir, I think I may want to rephrase my question. Sorry I am having hard time explaining this question.

Comment: For example, the rule is that values of x0, x1 should be one among first set of values of y {2, 6, 7, 8}. Values of x2, x3 should be amonst the second set of values of y  {1, 2, 3} and so on. Thank you for trying to guide me as quickly as possible

Comment: OK, now I understand better. Does `y` still contain plain integers?

Comment: Yes Sir. y contains the same input; plain integers

Comment: Thank you Sir. This is what I had in mind. Thank you for guiding me.